# Public property bound to button outside of class doesn't have the same value as button bound internally when object is instantiated

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, class, object

Overall, I have an object that keeps track of selected checkbox IDs. The way it does this is by pushing/slicing the IDs into/out of an array, `$Grid.selectedRows`. This object also binds a 'refresh' method to a refresh button. I have a class that I created that object from, `KendoGridSelection`.

My issue is the button bound inside of the class shows the correct array values, while the button bound outside of the class with the public `selectedRows` property no longer updates after the `refresh` button is clicked.

For testing purposes, I have two `seeSelectedRowsArray` buttons:

1. `seeSelectedRowsArray` button (Bound internally)
2. `seeSelectedRowsArray2` button (Bound outside of class)

I am testing in Chrome Version 28.0.1500.95 m

Here is my code:

**JS**

```
var KendoGridSelection = function (gridID, pagerSelector) {
    var $Grid = this;
    $Grid.selectedRows = [];
    $Grid.gridID = gridID;
    $Grid.pagerSelector = pagerSelector;
    $Grid.grid = $($Grid.gridID).data('kendoGrid');
    $Grid.pager = $($Grid.pagerSelector).data('kendoPager');
    $Grid.gridCheckboxes = $('input[type=checkbox]', $Grid.gridID);
    $Grid.gridRows = $('table tbody tr', $Grid.gridID);
    $Grid.refreshButton = $('.refreshButton', $Grid.gridID);

    $Grid.bindUIEvents = function () {
        $Grid.gridCheckboxes = $('input[type=checkbox]', $Grid.gridID);
        $Grid.gridRows = $('.row', $Grid.gridID);

        // Row click event
        /*$($Grid.gridRows).click(function (e) {
            if (!$(e.target).parent().hasClass('k-hierarchy-cell')) $(this).find('input[type=checkbox]').click();
        });*/

        // Checkbock click event
        $($Grid.gridCheckboxes).click(function (e) {
            console.log('checkbox clicked!');
            e.stopPropagation();
            var $t = $(this);
            var checkboxID = $t.attr('id');
            var thisRow = $t.closest('tr');

            if ($t.is(':checked')) {
                thisRow.addClass('k-state-selected');
                // add to selected[]
                if ($.inArray(checkboxID, $Grid.selectedRows) === -1) $Grid.selectedRows.push(checkboxID);
            } else {
                thisRow.removeClass('k-state-selected');
                // remove from selected[]
                $Grid.selectedRows.splice($.inArray(checkboxID, $Grid.selectedRows), 1);
            }
        });
    }
    $Grid.gridPersistSelected = function () {
        $.each($Grid.selectedRows, function () {
            var $t = $('#' + this);
            if ($t) $t.click();
        });
    }
    $Grid.pagerChange = function () {
        $Grid.bindUIEvents();
        $Grid.gridPersistSelected();
    }
    $Grid.refresh = function () {
        $Grid.selectedRows = [];
        $Grid.gridCheckboxes.attr('checked', false);
        console.log('Refresh clicked.');
        console.log('$Grid.selectedRows: '+$Grid.selectedRows);
    }

    // Init
    $Grid.pagerChange();
    // $Grid.pager.bind("change", $Grid.pagerChange);
    // Unbind refresh button, then rebind
    // Refresh button
    $Grid.refreshButton.click(function(){
        console.log('reset!'); 
        $Grid.refresh();
    });

    $('.seeSelectedRowsArray').click(function(){
        console.log($Grid.selectedRows);
    });

    return {
        selectedRows: $Grid.selectedRows,
        refresh: $Grid.refresh,
    }
}

$(function(){
    window.activeThreatsGrid = new KendoGridSelection('.grid', '.pager');
   $('.seeSelectedRowsArray2').click(function(){
        console.log(activeThreatsGrid.selectedRows);
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class='grid'>
    <div class='row'>
        <label><input type="checkbox" id="item1"> </label>
    </div>
    <div class='row'>
        <label><input type="checkbox" id="item2"> </label>
    </div>
    <div class='row'>
        <label><input type="checkbox" id="item3"> </label>
    </div>
    <div class='row'>
        <label><input type="checkbox" id="item4"> </label>
    </div>
    <div class='row'>
        <label><input type="checkbox" id="item5"> </label>
    </div>
    <div class='pager'>
        <input type="button" value="refresh" class="refreshButton">
    </div>
        <div><input type="button" value="seeSelectedRowsArray" class="seeSelectedRowsArray"></div>
        <div><input type="button" value="seeSelectedRowsArray2" class="seeSelectedRowsArray2"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.row{background:blue; height:20px; width:100px; margin-bottom:5px;}
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fmpeyton/rmDwZ/)

### [Demo](http://ignitepixels.com/sandbox/kendo.html)

**What is happening:**

- When I click on multiple checkboxes, then click the `seeSelectedRowsArray`, I get the correct values in the array. I can do this however many times and still get the correct values.
- When I hit the `refresh` button, my `console.log`s tell me my `selectedRows` array is empty. Then when I click the `seeSelectedRowsArray`, the array is empty (expected). When I click the `seeSelectedRowsArray2`, the array still has values in it.

### **UPDATE 1**

What I have found is if I bind `$Grid.selectedRows` to a button click from within my class, it always gets the most current values, even after refresh. If I bind the public `selectedRows` to a button click outside of my class, after the `refresh` button is clicked, `selectedRows` no longer updates and gets stuck at the value just before the refresh.

**Why does the button bound internally show the correct array values, while the button bound outside of the class with the public `selectedRows` property no longer updates after the `refresh` button is clicked?**

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem lies in how you are returning/tracking references to the object.

In your constructor, you set `$Grid = this`

However, you return a new object as a result of the function:

```
return {
    selectedRows: $Grid.selectedRows,
    refresh: $Grid.refresh,
}
```

That returned object now only holds a reference to the current value of `$Grid.selectedRows`

When your `refresh` method sets `$Grid.selectedRows` to a new array it breaks the associated value from the returned object which remains set to the original array.

Change your refresh from:

```
$Grid.selectedRows = []
```

to:

```
$Grid.selectedRows.length = 0;
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rmDwZ/8/)

Comment: Is that just a guess? Or did you fork my JSFiddle and test? I would love to see it working.

Comment: Also, I did not use `$Grid.selectedRows.length` in any of my code.